# Drop down choice slides textbox to the right making it required, and undoing if other option is chosen

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how I can show and hide and make a field required or not using jQuery depending on a dropdown that is chosen.

So I have a drop down like below:

What I am trying to do is when Other from the dropdown is chosen, I want the other textbox (#other1) to slide out to the right of it and make that textbox required.

But then if another option from the dropdown is chosen I want it to slide back in and hide and make the textbox not required anymore.

I cannot figure out the correct way to write this JavaScript so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).on('change', '#boatfuel', function() {
 
 var other1 = $('#other1');
    var boatFuelOther = $("#boatFuelOther")
 
    if($(this).val()==='Other') {
        boatFuelOther.slideRight();
        other1.prop('required',true);
    } else {
        boatFuelOther.slideLeft().hide();
        other1.prop('required',false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix">
      <label for="boatfuel">Fuel:</label>
      <select name="boatfuel" id="boatfuel" required>
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Fuel</option>
        <option value="Gas">Gas</option>
        <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
        <option value="Electric">Electric</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    
    <div id="boatFuelOther" style="display:none">
      <label for="other1">Other:</label>
      <input type="text" name="other1" id="other1" value="" />
    </div>
```

**I can get it working with the hide and show option but I am really trying to figure out the slide out options.**

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to just show and hide like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/r711ut83/

Otherwise I tend to have issues when I slide right and then hide it, to make it re-slide right again, if the user is toggling back and forth. Using the code below:

```
$(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

```js
$(document).on('change', '#boatfuel', function() {
 
 var other1 = $('#other1');
    
    if($(this).val()==='Other') {
        other1.show();
        other1.prop('required',true);
    } else {
        other1.hide();
        other1.prop('required',false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix">
      <label for="boatfuel">Fuel:</label>
      <select name="boatfuel" id="boatfuel" required>
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Fuel</option>
        <option value="Gas">Gas</option>
        <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
        <option value="Electric">Electric</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    
      <label for="other1" style="display:none">Other:</label>
      <input style="display:none" type="text" name="other1" id="other1" value="" />
    </div>
```